# After adding "MVC 5 controller with views, using Entity Framework" I get a DbUpdateConcurrencyException

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've been doing asp.net mvc project (internet shop) and when I've added "MVC 5 controller with views, using Entity Framework".

I get a

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException:
>   'store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0).

My code:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Item item)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryId", "Name", item.CategoryId);
        ViewBag.ProducerId = new SelectList(db.Producers, "ProducerId", "Name", item.ProducerId);
        return View(item);
}
```

In the HttpPost method 'Edit' there is a statement `db.SaveChanges();`. The compiler has stopped directly on this string. And throw me that exception, which I have indicated in the header of the question.

Basically, as I have learned from this article "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application",

Comment: It appears, that I've just solved problem, but I don't understand why it works.

Comment: I've removed this attribute [Bind(Exclude = "ItemId")]

Comment: Maybe someone have helpful ideas?

Comment: Maybe my solution is wrong?

Comment: How are you handling your context lifetime? In a web application, you want it to close after you fetch, update, etc. See [here](http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/)